# Can anyone help me out in aligning the layout in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, mobile-development

Below is the screenshot with incorrect layout:

[image: Screenshot for reference]

As you can see above, a column inside a row is pushing other children down.

I have removed the column from the row and the layout was displaying as expected. However, I need that column to be part of the row.

```
class TitleSection extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement build
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Kratos",style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20
                  )),
                  Text("The God Of War",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[500]
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.star,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Text("143")
          ],
        )
      );
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than wrapping your `Column` with `Expanded` which will occupy as much space as possible use `Flexible`, also wrap you other widgets inside a `Column` so you can easily lay them out :

```
 class TitleSection extends StatelessWidget{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Kratos",style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20
                )),
                Text("The God Of War",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[500]
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.star,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Text("143")
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks for that..! Expanded is also working only if I put the entire widget in a Column. I dont understand why!!

Comment: Not alt all :) !